# Integrate Firebase Analytics with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

There is no official documentation for analytics integration with xamarin. Only Xamarin [Google Analytics Sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/google-services/Analytics/) is available officially.

But we found an official Firebase nuget package [Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics/) has been available for analytics  which is provided by microsoft.

But there is no proper document to configure firebase with xamarin. We have created app id and .json file got generated from firebase console for our application. But there is no reference to configure these in xamarimn android app.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you do not need to have a official documentation for basic Android code conversion anything as simple as tracking code that is used by Android studio is directly available in the C# side:

Add the FirebaseAnalytics global field in your activity like this:

```
FirebaseAnalytics firebaseAnalytics;
```

Then get its instance in Activity Context :

```
firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.GetInstance(this);
```

Then define a bundle and log events:

```
var bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemId, "1");
bundle.PutString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ItemName, PageNameToTrack);
firebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SelectContent, bundle);
```

Reference can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/

**Update**

In context to the GoogleServices.Json just add it to your root folder of the project and set build action as GoogleServicesJson

Follow the following steps:

- Copy google-services.json to the project folder.
- Add google-services.json to the app project (click Show All Files in the Solution Explorer, right-click google-services.json, then select Include in Project).
- Select google-services.json in the Solution Explorer window.
- In the Properties pane, set the Build Action to GoogleServicesJson:

Official quote from FCM:

> When google-services.json is added to the project (and the GoogleServicesJson build action is set), the build process extracts the client ID and API key and then adds these credentials to the merged/generated AndroidManifest.xml that resides at obj/Debug/android/AndroidManifest.xml.

For [more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=vswin#add-googleplayservices-json)

Comment: How to include app id into xamarin application. And how to add .json file as part of xamarin app.

Comment: Check the answer again, and only downmark it if its wrong not if its in complete  thank you

Comment: yes the update works, thanks. And is there any reference link to integrate Firebase Rest API with xamarin andorid?

Comment: rest API for firebase database connectivity?

Comment: Yes rest API integration

Comment: Do we need to integrate with Crashlytics SDK for getting crash log in firebase?

Comment: Post that as a different question as that is just a new question all together also if this worked mark this as the right answer